# IE render background:transparent as a hole?

Tags: html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/PPdbc/4/) :

## HTML

```
<div class="myDiv">text under link!</div>        
<a class="myLinkTransparent" href="#">&nbsp;</a>    
<a class="myLinkRed" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
```

## CSS

```
.myDiv
{
    position:relative; 
    z-index:40; 
    width:310px;
}

.myLinkTransparent
{
    z-index:50; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    width:100px;  
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:transparent;    
}

.myLinkRed
{
    z-index:50; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; 
    left:100px; 
    width:100px;  
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:red;    
}
```

both link with transparent and red background should be "linked".

But in fact, on IE (every version I try: 7,8,9) the link is "broken", such as a "hole" to the text above the link.

Why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _hole_ but for me it looks exactly the same in FF, Chrome, IE8+...

Comment: If you go with the cursor over the text (that in fact is above the first link with transparent background) you can see it as "link" (you can't click on it). Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Of course, this on IE! On other browsers all works ok...

Comment: Oh I see now...Why are you using that weird markup? What are you trying to achieve? I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it.

Comment: This is my target : http://jsfiddle.net/y4dkF/4/ : putting an input text (with transparent background) over a custom styled text, emulating that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . The behaviour is not exactly as you expect originally due to `Normalized CSS` option set in JsFiddle by default (look at the left under JS frameworks choice and so). Lets remove it to guarantee we own all styles.

2 . However, just unchecking that won't fix it completely. You'll be able to sense it on the top left taking small width and height.

To fix the width, you need to set `display:block;`

3 . To fix the height, you need to set actual height. For example `height: 35px;`.

4 . After all this, you'll find the link is clickable only in areas that's not text, because the browser knows it's transparent, it thinks it's click-through also.

This behaviour is described here: http://haslayout.net/css/No-Transparency-Click-Bug

You need to apply the below fix (copied from article, just changed filename):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="non-existing-or-so.png",sizingMethod="scale");
```

.

The modified fiddle (tested in IE9 standards modes for IE9, IE8, IE7:

http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/PPdbc/11/

Comment: Found another intelligence solution : just add a background-image:url(../private_images/trasparenza_input.png); , with 1x1 px transparent! So, IE "understand" that there is some "background" and the problem is fixed :)

Comment: That's another route if you want to take. Was just focusing on the gist issue, but sure you can have a gif transparent image or whatever as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be a bug.

You can try the workaround below

- set **background-color** as green in myLinkTransparent class
- Then set opacity to zero just by setting **filter:alpha(opacity=0);** in myLinkTransparent class

  .myLinkTransparent
  {
  z-index:50; 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
  width:100px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:green;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  }